# Wakanda: inconsistent page draw issues

Tags: wakanda

(Edit) pages draw inconsistently. Across safari, firefox, chrome. Can't find a pattern. does not happen to some users at all. frustrating because I don't know if it is happening to our clients.

[image: Correct behavior and CSS]

[image: Incorrect behavior and CSS]

Comment: It really depends on your page layout. What I can tell you is that migrating to Wakanda 11 would not solve your issue. Once a widget is dropped on a page its CSS properties are calculated.

Since the CSSDOM is complex and full of terror, the result can't be perfect in every possible scenario.

In this case, and similar others, I suggest you to act on your CSS/Inline style and modify the faulty rules.

If you are lucky somebody with the same issue will come over and explain what happened.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is interesting that it does not happen at all on my test/localhost copy but happens in every browser when I connect to the remote/production wakanda server.

Comment: It's weird. I suspect it can be related to the fact that in your local environment the sources are not minified. There is a component, called WAF builder or similar, which is in charge of building your sources in a single file in a production environment. I think that the production version of your sources is not correctly built. But that's just a guess, I can't tell for what reason.